# Why have a confirmation page?

Tags: product-design

I am working on an inventory management software. At times, when users add a batch or products or transfer items around, they would have a confirmation page to confirm their action.

For example, I added 50 products, each in a list form stating the price and everything. I press next, and it gives me a summary of the number of products I added, the total cost and etc. But all these information can be seen from the previous page. Should there even be a confirmation page? Or should it just automatically add everything?

The confirmation page (for me) might be an overview of their actions. Maybe they intended for 50 products but they accidentally pressed 500 in the previous page. One of my developer argues that users can always check for confirmation before proceeding, making the confirmation page useless.

"Every page should provide some kind of value or else take it out". What kind of value does the confirmation page provide?

Comment: a good compromise might be 'save and add more' (or similar - essentially skip confirm and move on) allowing power users that trust the system to move on more quickly

Answer (score 3):

This is quite interesting to study the user actions and their confirmation. I agree with you, and you are right for somewhat, confirmation pages are overview of their actions.

I think it depends on the digital product or services or online transaction, these confirmation pages are delivering the different value.

- The first priority of a confirmation page is to communicate that the 
  transaction is done.
- A clear and bold completion statement with "what they did so far"
- Clear explanation of what next
- This page helps address the common concern “what if something goes wrong – what do I do?” and helps to reassure users.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you talk about, I don't think you need a confirmation *page*.

You need a confirmation or acknowledgement, but I can't think of a reason why there needs to be a screen dedicated to it.

The benefit of a confirmation or acknowledgement is that it leaves the user confident that the action they took caused the result they wanted, allowing them to move on without worry.

If you get in the way of that moving on with a full page, you're delivering that confidence in a way that prevents or delays your user from taking their next action.

Instead, see if you can find a way to give the confidence with some visual feedback that doesn't interrupt their next action?

My first thought for an alternative is to show a temporary notification bar near the top of the screen or a small message near the submit button that says (for example) "33 added successfully", *which goes away after a short delay*.  That message shouldn't stop the user continuing to do more on that page, but it does give them the confidence that their action happened as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I would infer that this may be a B2B application, but why not include a concept of a shopping cart instead?  Then you can show a count of the items in that "cart" and clicking it can take you to the details of that cart that includes your total costs.

[image]

On your cart, you can have a button that reads "Transfer" or whatever actions are eligible at that point.  You can maybe call the cart something like "Batches", "Lots", or "Parcels" if the word "Cart" feels out of context.

This would alleviate the need for any interim confirmation pages while also using a very common and well understood model.